# How to integrate TimePicker in Forms.py Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

```
forms.py

time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'timepicker'}))

Html

<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".timepicker").timepicker({});
        });
</script>
```

Im getting this error in my console 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function

How to integrate admin time widget in the django forms?

Comment: Have you include the relevant Javascript libraries in your template?

Comment: Yes i have included